# Could not convert string to float: '' in .prn

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to print the values between two heights in a prn file.

The error I have is that the delimiter just use one whitespace and not all.
The code works correctly because with .csv and .txt files works. I get the error in the first line of the loop because it's taking the second whitespace and not the first number. I tried too with a tab but the error that I got is list index out of range

This is the error I got

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> > "c:/Users/name/Desktop/script.py", line 86, in 
> >         col = float(row[4].replace(',','.')) ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

```
 with open(fileName) as File:  
                reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=delimiterOption)
                next(reader)
                for row in reader:
                    col = float(row[4].replace(',','.'))
                    if col>=float(height1)  and col<=float(height2)  or col==float(height1)  and col==float(height2) or col<=float(height1) and col>=float(height2):
                        print(row)
```

This is the .prn file

Example: If I put the values 133 and 135 should print the first line(name1)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified. 
The main problem is that we can't make use of a screen shot of your data.  If the problem is within the input process, then get rid of the later processing; a simple comparison will do.  If the problem is in the processing, then hard-code the data set.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having problems with your file because the `csv` module expects CSV files have their values separated by a single character. Your file's values are separated by several space characters, not just one. So it thinks that when you have a string like `"foo    bar"` (with four spaces in between the real words), you're actually looking at five values, the middle three of which are blank.

Fortunately, there is a way around this issue in this specific case. The `reader` class accepts a parameter named `skipinitialspace` which tells it to skip any extra whitespace immediately after a separator character. This works even if the separator is whitespace itself!

So try:

```
reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
```